Conditional probability of independent events and its interpretation
I've missintuition here, I know that if two events $A$ and $B$ are independent, then their conditional probability is $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$. But then, I try to speak about some interpretation behind it and I stacked. Suppose they are not independent, then $P(A\mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)} {P(B)}$, it is like we restrict our probability space $\Omega$ to $B$, because we know, that $B$ happend and we are interested only in the elementary events which could suttisfy event $B$ and find in them such that correspond to additional event $A$ which also could happen together with $B$ at the same time. But when these two events independent we know, that $(A \cap B) = 0$ for sure and if event $B$ happen there is no chance for $A$ appear together with it.
The probability of event $A$ in elementary probability theory is equal to $\frac{\mid A \mid} {\mid \Omega \mid} $ and it could be differ from $\frac{P(A \cap B)}  {P(B)}$, so if we suggest that this formula is correct for independent events $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$, which one probability for $A$ we should choose in dependent case: $\frac{\mid A \mid}  {\mid \Omega \mid} $ or $\frac{P(A \cap B)}  {P(B)}$?

Two events $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A\cap B)=P(A)×P(B)$ (and consequently $P(A|B)=P(A)$). They are mutually exclusive iff $A\cap B=\varnothing$ (and consequently $P(A\cap B)=0$). Two different concepts.

Yep. Agreed. See comments below.

Firstly, the formula $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$ is true regardless of whether $A$ and $B$ are independent or not.
If $A$ and $B$ are independent, then the LHS becomes $P(A)$ and so we obtain the result $P(A\cap B)=P(A)\times P(B)$ .
Secondly, $(A\cap B)=\phi$ (not zero, it is a set...) if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive. This is different to independent.
Hopefully this clarifies the situation somewhat.

but the $P(\emptyset)$ = 0?

Yes, but that is not what you said and words are very important.

okey, I am just clearifying last one thing: if two events are independent they mustn't to be mutually exclusive?

Independent has a very specific meaning. Mutually exclusive has a different meaning. One does not imply the other. If one event has probability zero then the events could be both Independent and Mutually Exclusive, but this would be quite a trivial case.

okey, than implications should look like what? if $A$ and $B$ mutually exclusive, than they are independent, but if they are independent then their intersection could be non-empty? Or what?

No. If A and B are independent they might be mutually exclusive, they might not be. If A and B are mutually exclusive they might be independent, they might not be. Neither can be assumed from the other.

The only way in which two independent events can be mutually exclusive is if at least one of them has probability zero.   If $\ P(A)>0,$$\ P(B)>0\ ,$ and $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ are independent, then $\ P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)>0\ ,$ so $\ A\ $ and $\ B\ $ can't possibly be mutually exclusive in that case.

I think I had this in an earlier comment, but thanks for agreeing.
